# rails 3: fields_for ordering after validation has failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, fields-for

In my controllers create method I am creating a parent & child(ren) objects using accepts_nested_attributes.  That all works fine.

The children have an ordering attribute which is correctly set.

However, when the validation fails (for a missing attribute say) the ordering of the child objects is *not* preserved when the fields_for method runs.

I have tried using parent.children.reorder("ordering ASC") but that doesn't work...

I'm happy to post any code should it make things clearer!

```
def create
  @parent = Parent.new(params[:parent])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @parent.save
      format.html 
    else
      @parent.children.reorder("ordering ASC")  #this makes no difference
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

---

and in the form partial

```
<%= f.fields_for :children do |ff| %>
  <%= render "child_fields", :ff => ff %>
<% end %>
```

Any pointers would be great..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am presuming that `ordering` is being set in your form, and the problem is that it is not taking effect when save fails. The reason for that appears to be that by sorting by `ordering ASC` uses the database, and since it's not saved it doesn't get sorted.

Try this instead:

```
<%= f.fields_for :children, @parent.children.sort_by(&:ordering) do |ff| %>
```

This will use `ordering` stored in memory, which should be what was previously submitted by the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure, but try:

In the controller

```
@children = @parent.children.reorder("ordering ASC")
```

In the view

```
<%= f.fields_for :children, @children do |ff| %>
    <%= render "child_fields", :ff => ff %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Tried that, it kills all the child objects (i.e. nothing is rendered in the form).